# bash configuration error : No such file or directory

Tags: bash

i am trying to run tests using phpunit from a directory with the following path:

`/home/rally/adserver/test/` by using the command `phpunit classes/AdTest.php`,
The command was working in previous times when i cloned the project but now for some reason after using `git clone` and `composer install` today i get this error:
`bash: /home/rally/tests/adserver/src/vendor/bin/phpunit: No such file or directory`

any help with how can i fix this or what is causing this? thx

Comment: Does that path exist? Can you show us exactly the sequence of commands you ran? What is `pwd` when you run the command?

Comment: FWIW, the path in your bash error does not match the first path you are running in (i.e., `/home/rally/adserver/test/` versus `/home/rally/test/adserver/...`).

Comment: the path doesnt exists anymore...i deleted it. pwd return `/home/rally/adserver/test`

Comment: "the path doesnt exists anymore...I deleted it" & what is expected behavior of the script now? Is it supposed to re-create the path? (Sorry, I don't know the commands you are running. Probably you need to re-configure something...) Also, a piece of advice, don't delete things, unless you have a working secondary setup. Rename the directory as directory.bak, in case you need to restore...